# How can I achieve a similar effect like the one in this photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can someone help me find the similar photo effect, I've to design a similar looking cover design for a school yearbook.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I suspect this is more than a "photo effect". Usually, designs like this are created manually using many different techniques involving the use of multiple layers, layer masks, layer blending modes, texture images, etc.   What I would suggest you do is look up some Photoshop photo manipulation tutorials. You won't find an exact tutorial matching this, but the skills and techniques you will learn can be used for edits like this.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Blender

I made a little video demo of me creating a book cover in a free 3D program called Blender, inspired by the image attached: https://youtu.be/ucsbB3IfdkQ

[image]
[image]

To create these variations of the piece, I simply played around with the settings under Properties Editor > Render Proprties > Color Management:
[image]

Increasing the contrast gets rid of the gray in the white and makes it possible to achieve to #FFFFFF (above blue image uses medium/high contrast/look, the purple one uses the default None contrast/look).

You can see all the keyboard shortcuts used in bottom right of the video, in the beginning Im doing ctrl+A and then adding an image  from my clipboard using an addon.

Downloads:
https://www.blender.org/
https://yeetusblenditus.gumroad.com/l/ImPaste

Download the file I made:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/631473902614478850/1063984938396954634/allTheDetailsDesign.blend

---

### Using Krita

See: https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/blending_modes.html
You could stencil a bunch of orange squares and then multiply the pixels with a background image. Then you could use the same image as a transparency layer on top of that. Krita has an excellent Discord community if you wish to have more in-depth advice on this.

###### Though beyond its photo manipulation features, krita makes an excellent painting app as well, so simply handpainting the cover could surely be a more fun way of achieving this and would probably yield best results! For this I would highly recommend using a pressure sensitive drawing tablet, or an iPad. I use XP-Pen myself (which is more of a budget brand) & am more than happy

##### Thanks for reading!